# Can I cluster desktops to create a single ESXi VM pool?

Tags: vmware-esxi, virtual-machines

I have 8 desktops of HP Elite 8000 make with quad core intel and 16 GB ram each. Can I somehow club them to get a single ESXi interface where I can create multiple VMs for users to connect?

How many VMs of lets say Win7 with 2GB ram each can this pool support if possible?

I want to avoid purchasing dedicated hardware like Dell R430 which could solve the purpose

Comment: I have tried searching on Google but couldnt find anything relevant to combining hardware

Answer (score 0):

No - have you not read even the most basic of information on this? We expect much more from serverfault users sorry.

You could buy eight vSphere licences and a licence for vCenter, install ESXi on each box, install vCenter and create a single 8-host cluster - it would have 32 cores and 128GB of memory which would support around 48-96 of your VMs. But this would end up costing you more than just buying one decent standalone server and using the free ESXi licence on that, which would support the same number of machines. Also Windows 7 is end-of-support so why would you use that, and if you have a lot of similar VMs you'd do better looking at VMware's Horizon 7 product anyway.

Comment: So it sounds to me like the answer is actually "yes", but it just wouldn't be cost-effective to do so.

Comment: This sounds like a yes with the added cost. Apologies for sounding noobish but I am not really a server guy. Just another guy trying to find an answer to my problem. Sorry!

Comment: Well there's the added THOUSANDS of [insert currency here] - plus the terrible performance you'd get too - so yes, if you wanted to waste LOTS of money and time to make something that massively underperforms then I suppose the answer would be yes. But back in the real world it'd be a lot cheaper and more performant to just buy one or two servers fit for the job. Serverfault is for professional sysadmins, who do things in a professional manner, we don't dick about.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is "no". That is not how VMware vSphere is used. vSphere ESXi can be used to create clusters of a few dense servers (>8 cores, hyperthreaded, >128GB RAM) if you want to get your money's worth while maintaining some form of high availability.

What you are looking for is called "Grid Technology" which is a different stance than vSphere ESXi. A grid is kind of like a RAID for your compute and RAM. The technology exists, but is not sold as openly nor as widely accepted as vSphere.

If you want to install ESXi free on each computer, you could do this. But if you want a single pane to manage them, you will need vSphere Standard for each CPU socket/processor and vCenter Standard. This will probably cost about $20k.

If you're looking to set up a lab, there is vSphere Essentials that is about $500 and provides 1 vCenter Essentials Server and up to 2 CPUs on a max of 3 hosts (physical boxes).

If you're just looking to combine hardware for a single platform, then consider researching computer grid technology.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try researching more on the grid technology